# I thought I upgraded my Rails version, but it didn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upgrade

I have an app running on Rails 2.3.3.

I edited my environment.rb

```
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.8' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
```

Then performed `rake rails:update`

In my console:

```
>> Rails.version
    2.3.3
```

What am I forgetting to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try manually installing rails 2.3.8

`gem install rails -v=2.3.8`

In some env's this works better (I found this to be the case when using rvm).

Comment: Well. I did, but I'm not using RVM, and already many different versions of rails are installed. ( at least 8 )..

Comment: These are all my rails versions => rails (3.0.5, 3.0.3, 3.0.0, 2.3.11, 2.3.10, 2.3.8, 2.3.5, 2.2.2, 1.2.6)

Comment: Grep your code for RAILS_GEM_VERSION. Ensure you aren't setting it somewhere else as well (for instance environments/development.rb)

Answer (score 0):

try doing "bundle update", this will update the lock file.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just froze your rails gems into your project. This will force the application to load the frozen version. Just remove vendor/rails and you should be all set. Then you can freeze 2.3.8 if you need to. Is there a reason you aren't just going to 2.3.11?